# How to set Rhythmbox default for mp3 [Not working]

Tags: rhythmbox, music, mp3

**When I do a simple double click on my mp3-files the videoclip-player opens up. It's a super boring app for playing my mp3-files with. I try to make Rhythmbox the default for mp3-files.** But without luck.

If I right-click on an mp3-file and select Rhythmbox it opens and play the file. So I know it is there and works.

What I did:

**1.**
I Selected the Rhythmbox as default player for Music. Did not work it opens the mp3-file in the videoplayer (selected for videofiles and is only option to select for videofiles).

### [image: Pic that shows the selector I talk about]

**2.**
I did a right click on an mp3-file. Selected to choose default program for that file. (Even if Rhytmbox is the only app in the menu to select).

Anyway, the menu opens and I choose (the selected) Rhytmbox. The mp3-file opens in Rhythmbox. I close the file and double click any mp3-file. It opens in the damn videoplayer app.

**3.**
I try to find in app Rhytmbox a way to make it default for mp3-files. Only thing I find is to set preferred format. I select mp3 (even if I don't believe it is for what I want), and it does not work.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and used to Windows where everything works right out the box. So please be nice.. Ok!

EDIT:
It says I have **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are similar questions and answers in Ask Ubuntu that dance around the bush none of them cut to the chase (that I've found so far). You need to perform a few steps to get **Rhythmbox** as the default music player:

1. In **Nautilus** file manager navigate to any `.mp3` file.
2. Give the it focus with a single left click.
3. Hover the mouse over the top screen line (systray)
4. A menu is revealed on the systray from that select `File`
5. At the drop down menu select `Properties`
6. From the Properties window select the `Open With` tab:

[image: Nautilus Default Music Player]

Select `Rhythmbox` as the application and click the lower right button `Set as Default`

Comment: Ok... that worked. Thanx! I mark this as correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) And thank you for marking as correct answer. Many new users forget to do that.